# Getting videos uploaded by facebook page without requiring user to log in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get videos of facebook page using facebook graph api.

I get it to work when I use my personal access facebook accounts access token but if I try to use my apps token it returns

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 102
  }
}
```

Is there way to get pages public videos from the api by using app token?

If not, is there way to use just my personal access token and renewing it automatically without requiring the user to login. (Server would always make the request with MY OWN access token, not their)